# PostgreSQL "DESCRIBE TABLE"

Tags: database, postgresql, command, psql, table-structure

How do you perform the equivalent of Oracle's `DESCRIBE TABLE` in PostgreSQL with psql command?

Answer (score 3173, accepted):

Try this (in the `psql` command-line tool):

```
\d+ tablename
```

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) for more info.

Comment: I had originally accepted devinmoore's answer but I really like this one better. Not only does it describe the table but it also shows the metadata such as column descriptions and if there are any OIDs.

Comment: The `+` is really clutch, as PostgresSQL 9 only gives the in-depth description for views when you do `\d+ table_name`, rather than the simple `\d table_name`

Comment: \d doesn't work when you invoke it in PosgreSQL 9.1 through pgAdmin, Vinko's answer below is applicable to more cases

Comment: `psql -E` is handy to get the sql that implements `\d+` and similar (for use outside of the psql prompt)

Comment: Note: This only works from the command-line `psql` client. Under the hood, it issues a query to get the information from the server as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Error:  "did not find any relation named". This means you need to wrap your table's name in double quotes. Apparently, postgres will lower case your table name without them and therefore not find your table. Hope this helps anyone else who comes here and has this problem. :)

Comment: Whoever came up with a CLI interface that makes one letter commands that start with the same letter as *d*rop or *d*elete should not be designing databases.

Comment: This is a hard one to remember, keep confuding \dt (list tables in a database) with \d+ tablename (describe a table).

Comment: I always come here, and never remember the sytax :D... this is the 3rd time this month :D

Comment: Try below one too. It gives nice output.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513125/4005369

Answer (score 928):

In addition to the PostgreSQL way (\d 'something' or \dt 'table' or \ds 'sequence' and so on)

The SQL standard way, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100504/what-is-the-sql-command-to-return-the-field-names-of-a-table#100513):

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, column_default, is_nullable
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '<name of table>';
```

It's supported by many db engines.

Comment: select column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'table';

Comment: This is more useful than \d when you're stuck with an pre-8.4 psql and a post-8.4 server - the \d command is incompatible.

Comment: Also this command runs against RedShift, where `\d+` does not.  **This is the best answer IMO**

Comment: Wonderful, altought for postgres I'd add the schema name too

Comment: \d, \d+ do not work from Navicat. This little query is good enough! This should have been the answer!

Comment: I would add `ORDER BY ordinal_position` to make it even better.

Comment: update to @NewAlexandria : \d+ works in redshift now

Comment: This only lists columns with minimal information.  \d+ gives full DDL for the table including: defaults, nullability, nextval, precision, primary key, foreign keys, indexes, check constraints, and FK's from other tables.

Comment: @bradw2k Did you try SELECT *?

Comment: @Dan The 'columns' table doesn't hold info about things like primary key, foreign keys, indexes, check constraints.  In one project I left join from 'columns' to 'key_column_usage' and 'table_constraints' to pick up PK and FK constraints.  All the info is in that schema for sure.

Comment: This is actually the most precise answer, as Oracle's DESCRIBE will list only the column information and so does this command. All the other stuff reported by \d (indexes, constraints) are not part of a simple DESCRIBE, and often I don't want to see them - pity there's no \d- command to make psql be a little less verbose...

Comment: Works in `PgAdmin 4` Query Tool

Answer (score 80):

If you want to obtain it from query instead of psql, you can query the catalog schema. Here's a complex query that does that:

```
SELECT  
    f.attnum AS number,  
    f.attname AS name,  
    f.attnum,  
    f.attnotnull AS notnull,  
    pg_catalog.format_type(f.atttypid,f.atttypmod) AS type,  
    CASE  
        WHEN p.contype = 'p' THEN 't'  
        ELSE 'f'  
    END AS primarykey,  
    CASE  
        WHEN p.contype = 'u' THEN 't'  
        ELSE 'f'
    END AS uniquekey,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN g.relname
    END AS foreignkey,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN p.confkey
    END AS foreignkey_fieldnum,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN g.relname
    END AS foreignkey,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN p.conkey
    END AS foreignkey_connnum,
    CASE
        WHEN f.atthasdef = 't' THEN pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)
    END AS default
FROM pg_attribute f  
    JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = f.attrelid  
    JOIN pg_type t ON t.oid = f.atttypid  
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON d.adrelid = c.oid AND d.adnum = f.attnum  
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace  
    LEFT JOIN pg_constraint p ON p.conrelid = c.oid AND f.attnum = ANY (p.conkey)  
    LEFT JOIN pg_class AS g ON p.confrelid = g.oid  
WHERE c.relkind = 'r'::char  
    AND n.nspname = '%s'  -- Replace with Schema name  
    AND c.relname = '%s'  -- Replace with table name  
    AND f.attnum > 0 ORDER BY number
;
```

It's pretty complex but it does show you the power and flexibility of the PostgreSQL system catalog and should get you on your way to pg_catalog mastery ;-).  Be sure to change out the %s's in the query. The first is Schema and the second is the table name.

Comment: This query is better shown [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL#Language_Constructs) note that they suggest "\d table" too

Comment: One advantage of this solution is that `format_type()` will include any modifiers attached to the type, e.g. `numeric(6,2)`; whereas `information_schema.columns` will only report the base type of `numeric`.

Comment: How do I split the data type from the size? say | character varying(50) | to 2 columns:  | character varying  |  50  |

Comment: Fails in v12, because pg_attrdef.adsrc does not exist anymore.

Comment: @RonJohn I updated it for v12, just replacing `d.adsr`c with `pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)` works fine

Answer (score 68):

You can do that with a psql slash command:

```
 \d myTable describe table
```

It also works for other objects:

```
 \d myView describe view
 \d myIndex describe index
 \d mySequence describe sequence
```

Source: [faqs.org](http://www.faqs.org/docs/ppbook/c4890.htm)

Answer (score 52):

This should be the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
   AND table_name   = 'your_table'
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer. If you are not getting any rows back, try this. One must always provide schema name when in doubt.

Answer (score 48):

The psql equivalent of `DESCRIBE TABLE` is `\d table`.

See the psql portion of the PostgreSQL manual for more details.

Comment: Also, psql database selction is `\c databasename` rather than                                   `use databasename` (for those coming from MySQL like myself :-). Without `\c databasename` first, `\d tablename` produces `No relations found.` message and nothing more.

Comment: Well, you can just `\d databasename.tablename` too. With proper quoting if necessary, i.e.  `\d "DatabaseName"."TableName"`, if your names are not all lowercase.

Answer (score 23):

You may do a `\d    *search pattern    *` **with asterisks** to find tables that match the search pattern you're interested in.

Comment: This was what I was looking for - how to describe a __subset__ of tables.  Of note, I also found that if your tables have uppercase, the syntax is `\d *"<SubString>"*`.  That is, the double quotes must be _inside_ the asterisks.  Though, if you just want the __list__ of tables then you want to use `\dt`

Comment: this matches sequences and indexes as well as tables

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the command line `\d+ <table_name>` you already found, you could also use the [information-schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) to look up the column data, using [info_schema.columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM info_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND table_name   = 'your_table'
```

Comment: `FROM info_schema.columns` didn't work for me I had to use `from information_schema.columns`, not sure if that's a typo in your answer or some implementation issue at my end.

Answer (score 16):

Use the following SQL statement

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name'
```

If you replace tbl_name and col_name, it displays data type of the particular coloumn that you looking for.

Comment: That's what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/109337/19068) from 2008 says.

Comment: @Quentin-There is difference in both of them..the above 2008 Solution describes column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length for the whole table. Where as mine -  the mentioned solution -  only shows  the data type of the schema column. Run both and check. They both are different. All the solutions here are different ways to solve a problem. User can use this for different reasons

Answer (score 15):

You can use this :

```
SELECT attname 
FROM pg_attribute,pg_class 
WHERE attrelid=pg_class.oid 
AND relname='TableName' 
AND attstattarget <>0;
```

Answer (score 11):

In **MySQL** , DESCRIBE table_name

---

In **PostgreSQL** , \d table_name

---

Or , you can use this long command:

```
SELECT
        a.attname AS Field,
        t.typname || '(' || a.atttypmod || ')' AS Type,
        CASE WHEN a.attnotnull = 't' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Null,
        CASE WHEN r.contype = 'p' THEN 'PRI' ELSE '' END AS Key,
        (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), '\'(.*)\'')
                FROM
                        pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                WHERE
                        d.adrelid = a.attrelid
                        AND d.adnum = a.attnum
                        AND a.atthasdef) AS Default,
        '' as Extras
FROM
        pg_class c 
        JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
        JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint r ON c.oid = r.conrelid 
                AND r.conname = a.attname
WHERE
        c.relname = 'tablename'
        AND a.attnum > 0

ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 9):

This variation of the query (as explained in other answers) worked for me.

```
SELECT
 COLUMN_NAME
FROM
 information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
 TABLE_NAME = 'city';
```

It's described here in details:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/

Answer (score 8):

In postgres \d is used to describe the table structure.

e.g. `\d schema_name.table_name`

this command will provide you the basic info of table such as, columns, type and modifiers.

If you want more info about table use

```
\d+ schema_name.table_name
```

this will give you extra info such as, storage, stats target and description

Answer (score 8):

To improve on the other answer's SQL query (which is great!), here is a revised query. It also includes constraint names, inheritance information, and a data types broken into it's constituent parts (type, length, precision, scale). It also filters out columns that have been dropped (which still exist in the database).

```
SELECT
    n.nspname as schema,
    c.relname as table,
    f.attname as column,  
    f.attnum as column_id,  
    f.attnotnull as not_null,
    f.attislocal not_inherited,
    f.attinhcount inheritance_count,
    pg_catalog.format_type(f.atttypid,f.atttypmod) AS data_type_full,
    t.typname AS data_type_name,
    CASE  
        WHEN f.atttypmod >= 0 AND t.typname <> 'numeric'THEN (f.atttypmod - 4) --first 4 bytes are for storing actual length of data
    END AS data_type_length, 
    CASE  
        WHEN t.typname = 'numeric' THEN (((f.atttypmod - 4) >> 16) & 65535)
    END AS numeric_precision,   
    CASE  
        WHEN t.typname = 'numeric' THEN ((f.atttypmod - 4)& 65535 )
    END AS numeric_scale,       
    CASE  
        WHEN p.contype = 'p' THEN 't'  
        ELSE 'f'  
    END AS is_primary_key,  
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'p' THEN p.conname
    END AS primary_key_name,
    CASE  
        WHEN p.contype = 'u' THEN 't'  
        ELSE 'f'
    END AS is_unique_key,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'u' THEN p.conname
    END AS unique_key_name,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN 't'
        ELSE 'f'
    END AS is_foreign_key,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN p.conname
    END AS foreignkey_name,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN p.confkey
    END AS foreign_key_columnid,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN g.relname
    END AS foreign_key_table,
    CASE
        WHEN p.contype = 'f' THEN p.conkey
    END AS foreign_key_local_column_id,
    CASE
        WHEN f.atthasdef = 't' THEN d.adsrc
    END AS default_value
FROM pg_attribute f  
    JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = f.attrelid  
    JOIN pg_type t ON t.oid = f.atttypid  
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON d.adrelid = c.oid AND d.adnum = f.attnum  
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace  
    LEFT JOIN pg_constraint p ON p.conrelid = c.oid AND f.attnum = ANY (p.conkey)  
    LEFT JOIN pg_class AS g ON p.confrelid = g.oid  
WHERE c.relkind = 'r'::char  
    AND f.attisdropped = false
    AND n.nspname = '%s'  -- Replace with Schema name  
    AND c.relname = '%s'  -- Replace with table name  
    AND f.attnum > 0 
ORDER BY f.attnum
;
```

Answer (score 7):

When your table name starts with a capital letter you should put your table name in the quotation.

Example: `\d "Users"`

Comment: One of those weird idiosyncrasies of databases...

Answer (score 5):

You can also check using below query

```
Select * from schema_name.table_name limit 0;
```

Expmple : My table has 2 columns name and pwd. Giving screenshot below.

[image: Adding image]

*Using PG admin3

Comment: because selecting and expecting the pgadmin to pickup the slack of getting the meta data is not "best practice"

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause is evaluated _after_ both `FROM` and `SELECT`; therefore, this query would take a **long** time to finish if the table in question is large.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to describe a table such as a column, type, modifiers of columns, etc.

```
\d+ tablename or \d tablename
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Use this command 

\d table name

like 

\d queuerecords

             Table "public.queuerecords"
  Column   |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id        | uuid                        | not null
 endtime   | timestamp without time zone |
 payload   | text                        |
 queueid   | text                        |
 starttime | timestamp without time zone |
 status    | text                        |
```

Answer (score 4):

When your table is not part of the default schema, you should write:

```
\d+ schema_name.table_name
```

Otherwise, you would get the error saying that "the relation doesn not exist."

Answer (score 3):

[\dt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DE) can describe multiple tables simply:

```
\dt
```

[\dt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DE) can describe a single table simply:

```
\dt <table>
```

[\d](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-D) can describe multiple tables in detail:

```
\d <table> <table>
```

[\d+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-D) can describe multiple tables in more detail:

```
\d+ <table> <table>
```

In addition, [pg_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html) can describe a table simply:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = '<table>';
```

And, [information_schema.columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) can describe a tables in much more detail:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '<table>';
```

Comment: None of these worked for me.

Comment: @Riveascore You should restore a backup because your database is corrupted. You can see => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74984279/pg-dump-missing-pg-catalog-pg-roles-relation/77842288#77842288

Answer (score 1):

**1) PostgreSQL DESCRIBE TABLE using psql**

In psql command line tool, **\d table_name** or **\d+ table_name** to find the information on columns of a table

**2) PostgreSQL DESCRIBE TABLE using information_schema**

SELECT statement to query the column_names,datatype,character maximum length of the columns table in the information_schema database;

**SELECT
COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tablename';**

For more information https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/

Answer (score 1):

To get description use,

```
SELECT  column_name, data_type, is_nullable FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table_name';
```

To get the indexes use,

```
SELECT indexname, indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'table_name' ORDER BY indexname;
```

Answer (score 0):

/dt is the commad which lists you all the tables present in a database. using
/d command and /d+ we can get the details of a table. The sysntax will be like
* /d table_name (or) \d+ table_name

Answer (score 0):

I'll add the pg_dump command even thou the psql command was requested. because it generate an output more common to previous MySQl users.

`# sudo -u postgres pg_dump --table=my_table_name --schema-only mydb`

Answer (score -2):

I worked out the following script for get table schema.

```
'CREATE TABLE ' || 'yourschema.yourtable' || E'\n(\n' ||
array_to_string(
array_agg(
'    ' || column_expr
)
, E',\n'
) || E'\n);\n'
from
(
SELECT '    ' || column_name || ' ' || data_type || 
coalesce('(' || character_maximum_length || ')', '') || 
case when is_nullable = 'YES' then ' NULL' else ' NOT NULL' end as column_expr
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema || '.' || table_name = 'yourschema.yourtable'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
) column_list;
```

Comment: `||` appears to be something like a concatenation operator (joining strings together)