# Help insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, odoo

Hi and thank you for reading.

I have two tables with the same columns. I would like to first table's data to second table. Insert query is very simple: `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2`. But my problem is when I upgrade `OpenERP`, table column positions are changed. So `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2` query doesn't work. Can you help me to solve this???? Any answers will be highly appreciated...thank you!!!

```
Table1:           Table2:
NAME   COUNT      NAME   COUNT
name1  1          name3  3
name2  2          name4  4
name3  3          name5  5
name4  4          name6  6
```

**SOLUTION:** Use information_schema.columns table.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name='tablename'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name1, name2, name3, name4) 
    SELECT name3, name4, name5, name6
    FROM Table2;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I can't use it. Because I'm write this query to so many tables. I need very flexible query like 'INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2'

Comment: I recommend doing a "DESCRIBE tableName" SQL query to get the fields of a table then dynamically creating the query above.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed you were using MySQL (DESCRIBE TABLE tableName).  Here's the correct solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table

Comment: You probably want Vinko Vrsalovic's answer from that link, the `\d tablename` command is for the `psql` command line tool but using `information_schema` will work from any old connection to the database.