# Is there something like show create database in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to use something like Mysql command to show me the structure of postgres tables in a database, Is there a way for it? I main goal is to create an exact copy of the table in another database with postgres sql.

I tries /d+ command, but got the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \d
```

My OS is windows XP SP3.
I've read the following post but gain no success:
[postgres question about descibe table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table)

**EDIT:**
\d+ command output on windows  :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \d+
```

Comment: I've read that and as I said I got an error.

Comment: Command `\d` (not `/d`!) works fine for me on Windows in `psql` console

Comment: I don't have access to psql. database is on server and I just can see databases through phppgAdmin