# Use table description in Hive query

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I would like to use `DESCRIBE table` statement results dynamically in another query in Hive. Is it possible? I cannot find any proper way of solving this problem.

It should be similar to using `all_tab_columns` view from Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: Question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005191/query-hive-meta-store/35012810

Comment: And, AFAIK, there is no equivalent in Hive to an `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The `describe extended` statement will dump some JSON vomit at the end but it's just for display, you cannot pipeline it in another query. Bottom line: the Java API is the way to go...

Comment: The question is similiar but not equal, because what I really need is column type. Thanks for your anwer.