# Hive metastore to sys

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, metastore, hive-metastore

What is the best approach to extracting a SQL Server sys-like view of the Hive metastore using one of: Impala, Hive, Pig?

Note: I do not have access to an ssh to the HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the Hive metastore tables from Hive, Impala, or Pig. You would use the appropriate JDBC connection driver directly to the metastore database.

And you don't need SSH, neccesarily, assuming the ports & grants for the metastore are remotely accessible.

Comment: My first thoughts were to string together SHOW/DESCRIBE statements, but I'm not familiar enough with the ecosystem to get them to construct a table like INFORMATION_SCHEMA in one workflow. Now I wonder if I have JDBC access... Thanks for the response.

Comment: And I'm not all that familiar with mysql, but sounds like you're just looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/35004455/2308683

Comment: 100% what I WANT to do, but I don't have access to a shell with HDFS, nor am I provided the connection information to set one up to our cluster. I'm an analyst, not an admin, so I'm looking for a "hack" approach given the querying technologies.

Comment: I know a few analysts that are using the Beeline Docker container from sequenceiq to connect to the Hive server from a local machine. You don't need direct shell access. You just need some shell and the Hive CLI or Beeline with the appropriate server address