# Hive query to see all the tables and columns of a database

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am looking for a single hive query that shows a list of tables and columns of a database in this format:

Table name, Column name

**Note: I know this question is already asked, but I didn't find any working answer that works on Dbeaver because I don't have access to the Linux terminal related to the database**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all table definitions in a database in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004455/how-to-get-all-table-definitions-in-a-database-in-hive)

Comment: I already saw it, but I cannot run any of the answers directly in dbeaver.