# Npgsql for c# how to access table scripts, views, foreign and primary keys and script them out

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am coding in c# with the Npgsql package. I have connected to Postgresql like this

```
  string connString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id= {2};Password={3};Database={4};", serverName, "5432", username, password,databaseName);
  NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
  conn.Open();
```

Is there any way that I could access the the tables,views,primary keys and foreign keys and generate create scripts for them from c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain Npgsql does not have any built-in way of generating CREATE scripts, but you can access schema information like the [second answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109337/10320).

You can also have a look at how pgAdmin III generates the CREATE scripts by looking at the various `pgadmin/schema/pg*.cpp` source files, for example, [here is how pgAdmin III generates SQL for a table](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin3/blob/master/pgadmin/schema/pgTable.cpp#L316). You can also have a look at how psql describes tables [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/psql/describe.c#L1201), and there is the [monstrous pg_dump utility too](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c).

You could possibly just call `pg_dump` with the appropriate flags from within your app and process the output accordingly, but this could introduce distribution issues if your app's license is incompatible with whatever license `pg_dump` falls under.

If calling `pg_dump` is out of the question, you could possibly create a library from the pgAdmin III or `pg_dump` source code and use that within your app (if licensing permits). The last thing you want to do is roll your own implementation.