# Getting exception while executing sql syntax

Tags: postgresql

describe syntax is not working in PLSql :

I am using below syntax :

```
DESCRIBE tblcustomer;
```

I am getting below exception after executing above query :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESCRIBE"
LINE 1: DESCRIBE tblcustomer;
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "DESCRIBE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table

Comment: Where in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `describe`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
\d tblcustomer
```

or this for more details

```
\d+ tblcustomer
```

List available `\…` commands

```
\?
```

Comment: Getting exception : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \d tblcustomer;
        ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1

Comment: are you using the `psql` command line client?

Comment: No. I am using postgres sql browser