# PostgreSQL - Determine column storage type

Tags: postgresql

I've been reading a lot about PostgreSQL's [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html), and there's one thing I seem to be missing. They mention in the documentation that, "there are four different strategies for storing TOAST-able columns on disk," those being: PLAIN, EXTENDED, EXTERNAL, and MAIN. They also have a very clear way to define which strategy to use for your column, which can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html). Essentially, it would be something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET STORAGE EXTERNAL
```

The one thing I don't see is how to easily retrieve that setting. My question is, is there a simple way (either through commands or pgAdmin) to retrieve the storage strategy being used by a column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is stored [`pg_attribute.attstorage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html), e.g.:

```
select att.attname, 
       case att.attstorage
          when 'p' then 'plain'
          when 'm' then 'main'
          when 'e' then 'external'
          when 'x' then 'extended'
       end as attstorage
from pg_attribute att  
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = att.attrelid   
  join pg_namespace ns on tbl.relnamespace = ns.oid   
where tbl.relname = 'table_name'
  and ns.nspname = 'public'
  and not att.attisdropped;
```

Note that `attstorage` is only valid if `attlen` is > -1

Answer (score 8):

While I like @a_horse_with_no_name's method, after I posted this question, I expanded my search to just general table information and found that if you use psql, you can use the command described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109334/8972283), and the result will be a table listing all of the columns, their types, modifiers, storage types, stats targets, and descriptions.

So, using psql this info can be found with:

```
\d+ table_name
```

I just figured I'd post this in case anyone wanted another solution.