# Delete a column postgres said it don't exist

Tags: postgresql

In a table I have this field

```
prepared boolean NOT NULL,
```

I try to drop column and do

```
alter table lcm.bnq
    drop column prepared,
    drop column put_freezer;
```

I get this mesage

> ERROR: column "prepared" of relation "bnq" does not exist

I see column in the table.

I tried

```
alter table lcm.bnq_durabilities
    drop column "prepared",
    drop column put_freezer;
```

Get same result

Any Idea?

Comment: do you have pgAdmin? You can delete a column there and check the generated sql query

Comment: most like it you have different table, different schema  or different field name , check here to see how describe a table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table

Comment: the table is `bnq` or `bnq_durabilities`

Comment: Post the result of `\d table_name` in `psql`.