# SQL queries from several tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I start the following query?

I have three tables `hasfriend`, `person` and `message`.

I want to run the following SQL query, output all persons once who have sent a message and are friends with a certain person.

The tables are constructed as follows:

- `hasfriend` consists of: email, emailfriend
- `message` consists of: id, fromemail, toemail
- `person` consists of: email, firstname, lastname

So my query now looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.firstname, person.lastname
FROM hasfriend, person, message
WHERE hasfriend.emailfriend = 'max.muster@mail.de' 
  AND (message.fromemail = person.email)
```

But it's not a good solution because the `hasfriend.email` is fixed. How can I solve this better?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please specify where the table `friend` is coming from ("I have three tables `hasfriend`, `person` and `message`")

Comment: Can you please show me how to do this with join in this example cause i have only learned it with comma...

Comment: @Luuk typing mistake cause this database was in another language...

Comment: Which database?  Because `SQL` is not a database, it's a language, and you did not specify which DBMS you are using (like: MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, ....)

Comment: Sorry PostgreSQL, and @Luuk ok, but i thin in this case i'd like to first solve the problem and than to use join. I mean step by step.

Comment: You specified that you only want to see 1 emailaddress (`WHERE hasfriend.emailfriend = 'max.muster@mail.de' `)   what happens when you delete that check?

Comment: Than i'll see everyone how has "send" a message and if this stands here there are only persons how has him as friend

Comment: [Joins Between Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) in the Postgres tutorial

Comment: It sounds like you have learned comma joins right now. If so, dismiss that book, tutorial or teacher immediately. You don't want to learn SQL as it was used in the 1980s. As to the task: what does "is friends with a certain person" mean? If that certain person is max.muster, are we looking for people that max.muster calls friends? Or are we looking for people who call max.muster as friend? Or must it be mutual? And must the person have just send any e-mail to someone or must it be an e-mail to max.muster?

Comment: Please add info (for all used tables) of how tables are created.   A Table like `hasfriend` with only the fields: email, emailfriend, is a very limited description. Becuse after this we know two fields, `email` and `emailfiend` but there is no information on who is is a friend of.

Comment: For getting table description see: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-describe-table/   OR    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table