# pg_dump: missing pg_catalog.pg_roles relation

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore, pg-catalog

I had created a DB `testDb1` on a postgres server. After adding some data to this DB, I created a dump of this data and restored that to a new DB `testDb2`. After that data was added to second DB for quite some time.
Now, I want to dump data of `testDb2` using following command:

```
pg_dump -U "postgres" --no-privileges -Fd -j 4 -f dump_20230102_db2 testDb2
```

But this gives me below error:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist
LINE 1: ....tableoid, n.oid, n.nspname, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog...
                                                             ^
pg_dump: error: query was: SELECT n.tableoid, n.oid, n.nspname, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = nspowner) AS rolname, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(n.nspacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) as nspacl, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(n.nspacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('n',n.nspowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) as rnspacl, NULL as initnspacl, NULL as initrnspacl FROM pg_namespace n LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (n.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_namespace'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0)
```

I checked the original DB `testDb1`, results are generated for above query but not for `testDb2`.

I also changed the owner of `testDb2` to postgres but no luck there.

What can I do to restore or generate pg_catalog.pg_roles for `testDb2`?

Update:

Both DB are on same version 14.4

Output of `\d *pg_roles*` in `testDb2` is:

```
testDb2-# \d *pg_roles*
Did not find any relation named "*pg_roles*".
```

Comment: More information needed: 1) The Postgres version(s) for the two database instances. 2) In `testDb2` using `psql` what does `\d *pg_roles*` return? 3) What happens if you try the dump without the `-j 4`?

Comment: Added the info above. After removing `-j 4`, same error is produced

Comment: Hmm `Did not find any relation named "*pg_roles*".` is not good.  If you do `\dt pg_catalog.*` does the table list match [System catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html)? Also does  `\dv pg_catalog.*` match [System views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/views.html), with exception of `pg_roles` ?

Comment: From system catalogs two missing: `{'pg_parameter_acl', 'pg_publication_namespace'}`. From system views I get error: ```testDb2-# \dv pg_catalog.*
Did not find any relation named "pg_catalog.*".```

Comment: Then someone/thing has dropped system tables and views. At this point you best bet would be to use `COPY` to copy the data out.

Comment: Okay, I get your point. Is there any way to restore or rebuild system tables and views ? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: For the views you could try in the database that works do `\d+ <view_name>` and use the displayed query to recreate the view on the other database. For system tables you could do `\d <table_name> and recreate. New thought you could create new database and use/set up [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to transfer the data and tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should restore a backup because your database is corrupted according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841140/d-and-d-got-relation-pg-catalog-pg-roles-does-not-exist-error-on-psql#77841266) to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841140/d-and-d-got-relation-pg-catalog-pg-roles-does-not-exist-error-on-psql).

Actually, I got the same error when trying to show the definition of `person` table as shown below, then I asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841140/d-and-d-got-relation-pg-catalog-pg-roles-does-not-exist-error-on-psql), then reinstalling PostgreSQL solved the error in my case:

```
postgres=# \d person
ERROR:  relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist
LINE 2: ...catalog.array_to_string(array(select rolname from pg_catalog...
```