# `\d` and `d+` got `relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist` error on psql

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, definition, dbtable

I created `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Then, trying to show the definition of `person` table with `\d` and `\d+` got the error as shown below:

```
postgres=# \d person
ERROR:  relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist
LINE 2: ...catalog.array_to_string(array(select rolname from pg_catalog...
```

```
postgres=# \d+ person
ERROR:  relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist
LINE 2: ...catalog.array_to_string(array(select rolname from pg_catalog...
```

*Memos:

- I use PostgreSQL `16.0` on Windows 11:
- I referred to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-D) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table#109334) which gets the highest upvotes.
- I also referred to `\?` on [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) as shown below:

  ```
  postgres=# \?
  ...
  Informational
    ...
    \d[S+]  NAME           describe table, view, sequence, or index
    ...
  ```

In addition, trying to show [pg_catalog.pg_roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html) got the error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles;
ERROR:  relation "pg_catalog.pg_roles" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles;
```

So, how can I solve the errors?

Comment: Using a fresh pg16 on win11 install, I can't replicate your error. 
Maybe check the search_path of your user?
Please provide the resulting query if you try to run \d after setting echo_hidden via \set echo_hidden.

Comment: @A.Copter my `echo_hidden` is `off`. So, do I need to make it `on`?

Comment: Just to verify do `select * from pg_catalog.pg_roles`.  My guess though is that the answer from @LaurenzAlbe is correct.

Comment: @A.Copter OK. I'll reinstall PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is corrupted. Restore a backup.