# Table Details in SQL Anywhere?

Tags: database, sqlanywhere

I just downloaded the developer edition of SQL Anywhere. How can I get a list of tables in the database I'm connected to?. Also for a particular table, how do I get the meta-data for that table (column names, types, etc)?

Comment: I got answer to part of my question regarding table details here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100504/what-is-the-sql-command-to-return-the-field-names-of-a-table

But still I don't know how to find the list of tables. I have got an idea though, let me try :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have not used SQL-Anywhere for many years however the following statement should work

```
select c.column_name
from systabcol c 
   key join systab t on t.table_id=c.table_id 
   where t.table_name='tablename'
```

This was cribbed directly from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100504/what-is-the-sql-command-to-return-the-field-names-of-a-table/100513)

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from systable  // lists all tables
select * from syscolumn // lists all tables columns
```

Answer (score 4):

For a particular table:

```
describe TableName
```

will return the table's columns, with an indication of the column's type, whether it's nullable and a primary key

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows: start - All Programs - SQL Anywhere 11 - Sybase Central

Then Connections - Connect with SQL Anywhere 11...

Select "ODBC Data Source name" and pick "SQL Anywhere 11 Demo"

Press OK to see a tree view of the various objects in the database (tables etcetera).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.name + '.' + a.name
  FROM sysobjects a, sysusers b
 WHERE a.type IN ('U', 'S')
   AND a.uid = b.uid
 ORDER BY b.name, a.name
```

This will yield a list of tables and users that have access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this view: http://dcx.sybase.com/1001/en/dbrfen10/rf-syvcol.html

Try

```
select * from sys.syscolumns
```

or just tables which you created:

```
select * from sys.syscolumns where creator=(select current user)
```

Answer (score 0):

System proc, [sa_describe_query](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/sa-describe-query-sysproc.html) is quite useful

`SELECT * FROM sa_describe_query('select * from TableName')`

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all tables used in the database :

```
select * from systable //without 's'
```

To get the list of all columns :

```
select * from syscolumn //without 's'
```

Answer (score 0):

select t.table_name, c.column_name, c.base_type_str, c.nulls from systabcol c key join systab t on t.table_id = c.table_id

http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbreference_en12/syscolumn345.html

Answer (score -1):

To select one table details

```
select * from Table_Name;
```

To select two different table and Map with id

```
select * from Table_1 t1,Table2 t2 where t2.id=ti.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

select * from user_tables;

desc tablename;

Comment: That is not valid for SQL Anywhere.