# Getting Table Field Names as a String

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to get the list of field names for a given table, to turn them into a string which I can to post back as a variable to another function.

I've Googled loads of stuff regarding GetSchemaTable but all I seem to be able to output are field parameters, but not the actual value of these parameters (ie ColumnName, which is the one I actually want!)

Found this page; [What is the SQL command to return the field names of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100504/what-is-the-sql-command-to-return-the-field-names-of-a-table)

But all the queries on there give me an error "You do not have access to Table 'Columns'"

I feel sure this is pretty simple, can someone give me a little function that will simply give me

```
fieldNames = "fieldName1, fieldName2, etc"
```

I am using a MySQL server and ODBC connections ASP.NET using VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but give it a try.

1. Instantiate a `OdbcCommand` with something like `select * from yourtable limit 0;`
2. Load a DataTable with the datareader returned from cmd.ExecuteReader.

   ```
    DataTable dt as new DataTable()  
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
   ```
3. Now iterate through the columns of dt to find out what the column names are.

This is *just and idea*. Don't know if it will work or not.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me forever to come back to this... but it works! Thanks. I've now decided what I was trying to do is a stupid idea mind you!!